# Get sum for column values and not allow to add new rows in UI grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I have a ui-grid with a column C with percentage value, we have a button "add rows" to add new rows in grid. One can add new row until this column C reaches 100%, one cannot add any more rows.

How do we define the grid options for it?

```
  $ctrl.structuringGrid =  {
             columnDefs : [
                  {
                     name : 'structurer',
                     displayName : 'Structurer',
                     headerCellClass: 'text-align-center',                  
                     headerTooltip: true,

                     editableCellTemplate: "<input name=\"structurer\" ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" uib-typeahead=\"user as user.name for user in grid.appScope.$ctrl.fetchUsers($viewValue)\" typeahead-select-on-blur='true' typeahead-min-length=\"4\" typeahead-editable=\"false\" ui-grid-editor>", 
                     cellTemplate: "<input style=\"height:26px;\"  name=\"structurer\" ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" ng-class=\"'colt' + col.uid\" class=\"form-control\" type=\"text\" uib-typeahead=\"user as user.name for user in grid.appScope.$ctrl.fetchUsers($viewValue)\" typeahead-select-on-blur='true' typeahead-min-length=\"4\" typeahead-editable=\"false\" ui-grid-editor>",
                     cellEditableCondition: true,
                     width: 200
                 },
                  {
                     name : 'Business',                    
                     displayName : 'Structuring Business',
                     headerCellClass: 'text-align-center',                     
                     headerTooltip: true,  
                     width: 200,
                     cellTemplate: "<select name=\"structBusiness\" model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" list-id=\"'STRUCT_BUSINESS'\" align=\"right\" edit-enabled=\"true\" disable=\"false\" custom-select-value=\"'value'\" ordering=\"'value'\"></select> ",
                     cellEditableCondition: true
                  },
                  {
                      name : 'SubBusiness',                    
                      displayName : 'Structuring Sub-Business',
                      cellTemplate: "<loud-select name=\"'structSubBusiness'\" model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\" items=\"$ctrl.subbusinessList\" align=\"right\" edit-enabled=\"true\" disable=\"false\" custom-select-value=\"'value'\" ordering=\"'value'\"></loud-select>",
                      headerCellClass: 'text-align-center',                     
                      headerTooltip: true,
                      width: 200,
                      cellEditableCondition: true
                   },
                   {
                       name : 'BusinessAllocation',                    
                       displayName : 'Business Allocation',
                       cellTemplate: "<input style=\"height:26px; background-color: #091c2b;\" type=\"number\" name=\"structBusinessAllocation\" ng-model=\"MODEL_COL_FIELD\"  text-align=\"right\" placeholder=\"0.00\" ng-max=\"99.99\"  ng-min=\"0\" > </input>",
                       headerCellClass: 'text-align-center',
                       aggregationType: uiGridConstants.aggregationTypes.sum,
                       headerTooltip: true,
                       width: 200,
                       cellEditableCondition: true,
                       height: 25
                    },
                    {
                        name : 'actions',
                        displayName : 'Actions',                    
                        headerTooltip: true,
                        width: 100,
                        enableFiltering: false,
                        cellTemplate: getButtons()
                    }
             ],
             enableSorting : false,
             minRowsToShow : 7,
             autoResize : true,
             enableHorizontalScrollbar : 0,
             enableVerticalScrollbar : 1,
             enableRowSelection : true,
             enableFullRowSelection : true,
             enableRowHeaderSelection : false,
             multiSelect : false,
             enableFiltering: false,
             enableGridMenu : false,
             onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
                 $ctrl.aGridApi = gridApi;

             }
         };
```

On Button click I have following code:

```
     $ctrl.addNewRow = function() {
         console.log(" Total business allocation -------------------------- " + $ctrl.GridApi.grid.columns[3].getAggregationValue());
         $ctrl.Grid.data.push({Id:'', structurer: '', business: '', SubBusiness: '', BusinessAllocation: ''});  
     };
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Used ng-change() to method to solve the purpose.